# Cannot open Android Studio Canary 15 | Arctic Fox

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, awt

I've recently run into an issue with the latest Canary build for Android Studio. I've been using it regularly for the last ~week and its been great. However today I tried to open android studio as I normally would and it won't open. Weird because I haven't updated ANYTHING(?!). Checking the logs it seems like there's an issue with AWT and its dependencies.

Since Android Studio uses its own packaged JRE I don't feel that I have much to try.

So far I have tried;

- Re-installing and running Android Studio (tried both .zip and .exe downloads)
- Wiping all android studio cached information in %appdata%/google/

Any ideas on how I could solve this?

### More Info:

**Studio Build**: android-studio-2020.3.1.15

**Version of Gradle Plugin**: N/A

**Version of Gradle**: 6.5.1

**Version of Java**: JDK 11 "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 LTS

**OS**: Windows 10 64-Bit x86

## Steps to Reproduce:

0. Use Windows 10
1. Download the Canary 15 .zip & extract (or .exe installer, and install) from https://developer.android.com/studio/archive
2. Run studio64.exe

#### Explanation:

Studio doesn't open anything, loading icon spins on mouse for a couple seconds then nothing.
Logs  say "UI initialization failed. (...) ${android_studio_install_dir}\jre\bin\awt.dll: Can't find dependent libraries"

#### Stacktrace:

```
2021-05-17 16:57:29,705 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,762 [     57]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - IDE: Android Studio (build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7321754, 29 Apr 2021 11:10) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,764 [     59]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - OS: Windows 10 (10.0, amd64) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,778 [     73]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JRE: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 (Oracle Corporation) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,778 [     73]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,782 [     77]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JVM Args: exit -Xms256m -Xmx1280m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m -XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=10000 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -ea -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.boot.library.path= -Didea.vendor.name=Google -Djb.vmOptionsFile=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe.vmoptions -Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\\bin;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\\bin\server -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio -Didea.jre.check=true -Dide.native.launcher=true -Didea.vendor.name=Google -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudioPreview2020.3 -XX:ErrorFile=C:\Users\username\java_error_in_studio64_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\username\java_error_in_studio64.hprof 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,783 [     78]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - library path: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\\bin;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\\bin\server 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,783 [     78]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - boot library path: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,817 [    112]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - locale=en_NZ JNU=Cp1252 file.encoding=Cp1252
  idea.config.path=C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioPreview2020.3
  idea.system.path=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudioPreview2020.3
  idea.plugins.path=C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioPreview2020.3\plugins
  idea.log.path=C:\Users\username\Desktop\log 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,875 [    170]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - JNA library (64-bit) loaded in 57 ms 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,947 [    242]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,949 [    244]   INFO -                         STDERR -  
2021-05-17 16:57:29,949 [    244]   INFO -                         STDERR - Start Failed 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,950 [    245]   INFO -                         STDERR - Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,950 [    245]   INFO -                         STDERR -  
2021-05-17 16:57:29,950 [    245]   INFO -                         STDERR - com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException: UI initialization failed 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,950 [    245]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$prepareApp$3(StartupUtil.java:194) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,950 [    245]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:986) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,950 [    245]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:970) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,950 [    245]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,950 [    245]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,950 [    245]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$scheduleInitUi$9(StartupUtil.java:375) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,950 [    245]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,950 [    245]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,950 [    245]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,950 [    245]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,950 [    245]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,950 [    245]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,950 [    245]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,950 [    245]   INFO -                         STDERR - Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\awt.dll: Can't find dependent libraries 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,951 [    246]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:331) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,951 [    246]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:346) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,951 [    246]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$BiRelay.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1423) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,951 [    246]   INFO -                         STDERR -     ... 10 more 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,951 [    246]   INFO -                         STDERR - Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\awt.dll: Can't find dependent libraries 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,951 [    246]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,951 [    246]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2442) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,951 [    246]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2498) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,951 [    246]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2694) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,951 [    246]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2648) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,951 [    246]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,951 [    246]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,951 [    246]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1395) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,951 [    246]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1393) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,951 [    246]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,951 [    246]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1392) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,951 [    246]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1430) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,951 [    246]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(EventQueue.java:1318) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,951 [    246]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$scheduleInitUi$9(StartupUtil.java:326) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,951 [    246]   INFO -                         STDERR -     ... 7 more 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,951 [    246]   INFO -                         STDERR -  
2021-05-17 16:57:29,951 [    246]   INFO -                         STDERR - ----- 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,951 [    246]   INFO -                         STDERR - Your JRE: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 amd64 (Oracle Corporation) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,952 [    247]   INFO -                         STDERR - C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,969 [    264]   INFO -                         STDERR -  
2021-05-17 16:57:29,970 [    265]   INFO -                         STDERR - Also, a UI exception occurred on an attempt to show the above message 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,970 [    265]   INFO -                         STDERR - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,970 [    265]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:626) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,970 [    265]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:317) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,970 [    265]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:270) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,971 [    266]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException.logAndExit(StartupAbortedException.java:86) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,971 [    266]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException.processException(StartupAbortedException.java:34) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,971 [    266]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$prepareApp$3(StartupUtil.java:194) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,971 [    266]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:986) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,971 [    266]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:970) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,971 [    266]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,971 [    266]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,972 [    267]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$scheduleInitUi$9(StartupUtil.java:375) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,972 [    267]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,972 [    267]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,972 [    267]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,973 [    268]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,973 [    268]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,973 [    268]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,973 [    268]   INFO -                         STDERR -     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) 
2021-05-17 16:57:29,975 [    270]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE SHUTDOWN ------------------------------------------------------ 
2021-05-17 16:57:30,251 [    546]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin PluginDescriptor(name=Database Navigator, id=DBN, path=C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioPreview2020.3\plugins\DBNavigator, version=3.2.3225.0) misses optional descriptor JavaPlugin.xml 
2021-05-17 16:57:30,286 [    581]   INFO - org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer - web server stopped
```

Comment: Installing https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe may help.

Answer (score 1):

Installing [aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe](http://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe) fixed this.

EDIT: Alternative download: [visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/)

Thanks to @y.bedrov